# Use npm package manager in SAP Hybris

Tags: node.js, cordova, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to use apache cordova inside SAP Hybris.

I saw that Hybris has some extensions like npmancillary that have nodejs and npm inside it.

But I could not find a way to execute npm as part of hybris and install the new packages I want.

How to use npm package manager inside the SAP Hybris build flow to install new packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My knowledge about nodejs in hybris: It is using for compiling scss and sass stylesheet in compile time. It is not included released project. On the other hand, you can host js/html files in hybris for cordova. You need custom filter with special root map for it.

Comment: I was wondering that would be the case. So it's available for internal use but not really exposed for customization and extension.

Comment: Yes. If you can running it anyway, yo need to use hybris sources for next step. At the end you need connection between nodejs and hybris. My opinion; you can use custom java codes for nodejs functionality and serve js/html files in hybris for cordova.